# Disable single heat sensor?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, temperature

I have a Macbook Air 15".  A few days ago, it started running extremely slowly, with the fan at max RPM.  I opened Activity Monitor and discovered that I had kernel_task running at about 400% CPU, despite the fact that my computer felt ice cold.  Turns out, one of my sensors (the GPU sensor, to be precise) is apparently acting up and reading a good 10 degrees celsius higher than any of the others.

My question is, can I tell the computer to ignore that one sensor?  The other sensors are all functioning properly, so I'm not worried about overheating.  I just want the machine to stop thinking it needs to compensate for nonexistent heat by slowing me down when I try to use it.  A software solution would be preferable, since I'm a relative idiot when it comes to hardware.

Comment: What makes you think it those 10° C higher are wrong?

Comment: it's better to fix it properly. disabling a sensor can make your laptop die when it does some more intense GPU work, because the heat will not be detected.